# OAuth Consumer Secret Consumer Key generation in scala

Tags: java, scala, oauth, cryptography

Im trying to create consumer secret / key pairs in my scala play application but i cant seem to get it to work correctly.
I have the following code

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
import javax.crypto.{KeyGenerator, Mac, SecretKey}
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec

def hmacSha1(baseString:String) : String = {
    val MAC_NAME = "HmacSHA1"
    val keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(MAC_NAME);
    val macKey = keygen.generateKey();
    val mac = Mac.getInstance(MAC_NAME);
    val secret = new SecretKeySpec(macKey.getEncoded(), mac.getAlgorithm());
    mac.init(secret);
    val digest = mac.doFinal(s.getBytes());
    val result= new binary.Base64().encode(digest)
    result.toString
}
```

but when i add in the baseString for something like "Anthony" I always get back a string that looks something like this

```
"[B@2008bf02"
```

where as i was hoping to get something that looks more like this

```
“w/FdJ7y1qwe3HX/VmPiACTn01Zc=“
```

Comment: binary.Base64() - is that short for org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64?

Comment: yep I will update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not converting the encoded byte array to a string correctly.  The Base64 class has a method to help you.  Just do this:

```
    mac.init(secret);
    val digest = mac.doFinal(s.getBytes());
    new binary.Base64().encodeBase64String(digest);
}
```

The more traditional way would be:

```
    mac.init(secret);
    val digest = mac.doFinal(s.getBytes());
    val result= new binary.Base64().encode(digest)
    new String(result, "ASCII");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I now get the following for the result "3vZ4DTt/qy/DmHER8OHdmW1TQ50="